# Benefit of interpreting blank space elements as valid factor elements in the R function factor()?

Tags: r, type-conversion, character, na

The base R function `factor()` interprets character elements consisting of blank space as valid factor elements instead of `NA`. What is the benefit of interpreting blank space character elements like this? Is it a legacy feature that is kept as it is to maintain compatibility?

Example:

> factor(c("a","a","","b"))

I realize that this isn't an ordinary problem that can be solved with a reproducible example as a starting point, but I decided to give it a try anyway. The design decision to have `factor()` interpret blank space character elements like this confounds me. It seems to me that it would simplify things with no clear disadvantages to interpret these elements as `NA` instead.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a difference between an empty string and a character NA?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there is a difference. However, within the usage of factor(), does it not make sense to treat "" as NA? What could go wrong with this interpretation when you are using the function factor()?

Comment: The factor function is most important for modeling. Some of us appreciate having the option of distinguishing empty string levels from NA values in our models.

Comment: Yes, I can see how it would be useful if you are dealing with very specialized data, for example the example Konrad used with titles and meaningful blank space elements. It seems like very specialized usage, though. Wouldn't the average user benefit more from a default setting of the function that treats "" as NA?

Comment: No. I don't know what issue you are trying to solve here. You can define how NA values are encoded when you import your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the benefit of interpreting blank space character elements like this?

Because empty string data usually means “this is an empty string”, and *not* “this is missing data”.

It depends on the usage of course: an empty “name” field is most likely missing data. But an empty “title” field is just that: no title. How else would you encode lack of a title (assuming “Mr” and “Mrs” have a separate field, which may not be the case).

For factors, having empty labels makes less sense. However, R tends to convert strings to factors quite liberally (especially when reading tabular data from files), and treating all those empty values as NA would cause a lot of mis-annotated data. In general, such implicit conversions should always be lossless, i.e. preserve the whole domain of values being converted.

Comment: But if the character elements are names it does not make sense to user factor() on them anyway? But it is plausible that someone would store a factor as character elements in a csv while denoting missing values as "".

Comment: @CarlAH Right, it doesn’t make sense for names but it totally does for titles. All the more reason to treat empty strings differently from missing strings. And if you denote CSV missing values via empty strings, I will hunt you, and I will find you, and I will make you change all these empty strings into “NA”. By hand. In Excel. Without search&replace. You have been warned.

Comment: I'm going to find a way to change all of Konrad's missing values to empty strings and deploy that on April 1.

Comment: That is a valid example. I guess the important question is how data is usually stored and what should be treated as an exception considering that reality. Obviously, in established R data sets, the distinction makes sense because most missing values will be entered as NA. On the other hand, I don't think there is a big need to use factor() to analyze titles, and I am not sure there are many other examples within the scope of using factor() that use a meaningful blank space element. When connecting data with external sources, I think it can be quite common with missing values not denoted NA.

Comment: To clarify, I think that separating blank space and NA can be very useful in other areas. This discussion relates specifically to how factor() should interpret elements.

Comment: @CarlAH I understand your point, and I’m inclined to agree that, specifically for factors, empty labels don’t make as much sense. It’s, in this case, just a conservative conversion. Especially since traditionally R would convert character strings to factors at the slightest provocation (e.g. when reading in tabular data).

Comment: Could you use some of the text from your last replay and nuance your answer a bit? If no one else checks in I will give you the accept in a couple of hours

Comment: @CarlAH Done that.